# Order array of objects by property date

Tags: javascript

how can i order this array of objects:

```js
var arr= [
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16487438090000)/' },
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16987438090000)/' },
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16887438090000)/' }
]
```

According to the 'date' property, how can I order from largest to smallest? example I want you to return me an array like this:

```js
[
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16987438090000)/' },
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16887438090000)/' }
  { name: 'Mario', date: '/Date(16487438090000)/' },
]
```

Comment: What is the type of the `date` property? Is it just a javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?retiredLocale=nl)?

Comment: @Titulum  yes  it just a javascript date

Comment: Since `date`s seem to be constant-length strings, you can even get away with a lexical comparison using `.sort` and `.localeCompare` or whatever.

Comment: @FZs How can i do?